# Using multiple TFS Templates

Tags: templates

Is it possible to use more than one process template simultaneously in TFS 2010?
I am thinking about using MS Scrum v1.0 but would like the enhanced use case functionality found in Agile use cases (http://www.ivarjacobson.com/VS2010/).

I get the impression that I would need to create a customised template, merging the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You can only apply one template to a team project.

You have the choice to either modify the template to add the Jacobson use cases, or add the use cases after you have applied the template.

In the first case you can reapply the modified settings to any team project, in the latter, you just make the modification once.